# CodeCommit Notification does not send event to SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-codecommit

I set up Notification in CodeCommit on all events. The rule target SNS topic has a policy that allows principal *. However when I created a pull request. There is no event went through my SNS topic. I have a email subscription to the topic.

What have I missed and what is the possible causes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having the same problem.

The solution is to give permission in SNS to receive notifications from CodeCommit. To do so you need to edit the SNS "Access policy" and add the following rule:

```
{
      "Sid": "AWSCodeStarNotifications_publish",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "codestar-notifications.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:codestar-notifications-MyTopicForNotificationRules"
    }
```

Just make sure to edit the *Resource* property first.

Source, full explanation and example here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codestar-notifications/latest/userguide/notification-target-create.html